# How to convert Munsell to LAB values in R

Tags: r, colors, rgb

I need to convert Munsell color codes to LAB values. 
I only know how to do this indirectly in R: I can convert Munsell to RGB (via munsell2rgb, package aqp) and subsequently convert RGB to lab (via convertColor, package grDevices).

Does anyone know a direct way to convert Munsell to LAB? (Preferably in R.)

Comment: The algorithm(s) are pretty simple, so why not roll your own?  I have some tools for Lab to RGB to HCS , etc., so if you'd like those send me a response and I'll post them to github.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to create my own, but I'd like to give it a try. Please post the tools, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fear I've lost track of my homebrewed conversion code, so here's some links to collections of conversion libraries.

First, in MATLAB, [MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox](http://www.99main.com/~centore/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox.html)

(and it's really easy to convert matlab code into R)

[casoilresource](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/software/r-advanced-statistical-package/color-functions/convert-munsell-colors-computer-friendly-rgb-triplets/)  has a bunch of R-code ready for downloading that should more than meet your needs.

Or how about the package `munsellinterpol` which also appears to have a lot of converters?

Comment: The link can't be opened due to security reasons and seems to be outdated. Here is live: http://www.munsellcolourscienceforpainters.com/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox/MunsellAndKubelkaMunkToolbox.html